# Balloon tip text must have a non-empty value exception

Tags: c#, wpf, notifications, system-tray, trayicon

I got "Balloon tip text must have a non-empty value" exception when the OnStateChange(). This method called when my application is minimized.

```
 void OnStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            if (WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
            {
                Hide();
                if (TippuTrayNotify != null)
                {
                    TippuTrayNotify.Visible = true;
                    TippuTrayNotify.ShowBalloonTip(2000);
                }
            }
            else
                m_storedWindowState = WindowState;
        }catch(Exception ex){
            SystemLog.WriteLine("(Error) OnStateChange : "+ex.Message+" ;");
        }
    }
```

I initial TippuTrayNotify within MainWindow constructor

```
     public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
         TippuTrayNotify = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon(); 
            TippuTrayNotify.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("Icons/icon_64.ico");

            TippuTrayNotify.BalloonTipTitle = "OlivInClass";
            TippuTrayNotify.Text = "OlivInClass";
            TippuTrayNotify.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(TippuTrayNotify_DoubleClick);
    }
```

Any solution please

Comment: Can you clarify when you are initialising `TippuTrayNotify`.  Looks like this may not be called before OnStateChange.  What happens if you set TippuTextNotify.Text just before the call to ShowBalloonTip?

Comment: I initialize TippuTrayNotify at the constructor of the MainWindow.xml

Comment: Please don't put the tags in the title.  I've removed the C# tag for you.

Answer (score 2):

`Text` appears to be what shows when you mouse over the icon, not the balloon tip text.  That's set via the `BalloonTipText` property.

Comment: If I don't want to set BollonTipText, how can I do?

Comment: Not sure.  Try setting it to " " (a single space) if you don't want anything to show up.  But why are you popping up an empty balloon tip?  Kinda defeats the purpose of balloon tips, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
notifyIcon1.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info;
notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "your text";
notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "Welcome Message";
notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1000);
```